# How to add a certain branch of TornadoFX to my project?

Tags: git, gradle, github, tornadofx

New to all this kind of stuff!

I pulled the latest version of TornadoFX into my project easily enough with:

```
implementation ( "no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.19" )
```

However from some errors I've been getting, it looks like I need the jdk10+ branch found [here](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/tree/jdk10).

The question is, how can I use this branch in my project instead of whatever default version gradle pulls from maven?

I'm using IntelliJ 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding

```
maven {
        setUrl("https://jitpack.io")

    }
```

to my `build.gradle.kts` and then `implementation ( "com.github.edvin:tornadofx:jdk10-SNAPSHOT" )` to my dependencies.